# On solvability of a null-divergence problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, fluid-dynamics, divergence-theorem

Recently, I've been working with a colleage on the numerical solution of some problems in fluid mechanics via the Van-Kan algorithm.

In the case we're studying these days, we've come across the following problem:

$$\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{l}
\partial_x G_1+ \partial_y G_2 = 0, \quad \text{in } \Omega\\
G_1(0,y) = y(2-y), \quad y \in [0,2], \\
G_1(x,y) = 0, \quad \text{in } \partial \Omega \setminus \{x = 0\}, \\
G_2(x,y) = 0, \quad \text{in } \partial \Omega,
\end{array}
\right.$$
where $G = (G_1,G_2) \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\Omega = [0,10] \times [0,2]$.

We are stuck in deciding whether if the upper problem has solution or not. We've notice that, if the solution exists, it must not be compatible with the Divergence/Green theorem (as the given boundary conditions do not integrate to $0$ on $\partial \Omega$). Any advice on the (non-)existence of solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems you are addressing "flow in a pipe" problems... If you have a fixed inflow with no outflow, the fluid cannot be incompressible.

Comment: My intuition is exactly the same. Is there any way to prove this mathematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution, as the divergence theorem can be extended to Sobolev spaces:

**Michel Willem - Functional Analysis** (Fundamentals and Applications) - Birkhäuser Basel (2013). *Theorem 6.3.4.*